# Do I need to use threading?

Tags: java, android

I need to fix some problem here. I am using java android eclipse.

Problem: If I click add or minus button it will execute those 2 methods, right?
What I want is:

1. If I click button at the same time it should only execute 1 method.
2. I don't want the add method will be executed simultaneously if i keep pressing the button.
3. I want to terminate the minus function if ever the add functions is still processing.
4. How to do this?

Question: Do i need to use threading?

```
public void Add(int a, int b){
     return a + b;
}

public void Minus(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}

public void btn_add(View view){
      Add(a,b);
}

public void btn_minus(View view){
      Minus(a,b);
}
```

Comment: You're not passing arguments to Add()...?

Comment: sorry my mistake with the arguments. but my main problem is not about the arguments.

Comment: Can't this be handled with mouse events? Down, release, pressing...

Comment: It can be. but it wont solve my main problem. If I press add it will execute the add function. but if the add function is still processing. i don't want to keep calling the add function when I keep pressing add button. You can only call the add function whenever the execution is done. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've simplified the tasks you want to perform into methods named `add` and `minus` but these are actually more complex tasks that take a non-trivial amount of time. (Otherwise, you wouldn't be worried about clicking again while they are processing).

So, I think you should use threading, but not to take on the complexities of creating and managing worker thread yourself. You should use `AsyncTask`.

So, the pattern would like:

```
public void clickAdd(View view) {
  if (mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
    return;
  }

  mTask.execute(...);
}

private AddTask mTask = new AddTask();

private class AddTask extends AsyncTask {
    public void doInBackground(...) {

    }
}
```

Comment: And to solve what the OP is worried about (other buttons being clicked while the first button's method is running), the `onClick` method should call `disable` on all buttons before starting the task, and the task's `onPostExecute` should re-enable them.

Answer (score 0):

Greg Ennis's answer assumes you're concerned because your actual methods are time-consuming, unlike your `add` and `subtract` example.

If that is not your concern, I should point out that if these are short-running methods, then you don't need to worry about threading at all. Don't specify any Threads, Runnables, or AsyncTasks. When a button is clicked, it's `onClick` method will automatically be called on the UI thread, so it will be impossible for any other button clicks to occur until the `onClick` method (and therefore your `add` method) returns.

Regarding your point number 1, I don't think Android permits simultaneous button presses.